# how to choose precedence of .First() on a specific collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
    //Pretend there is a few static values in this list
    List<string> repeatUserIds = new List<string>();

    SomeCollection.Where(x => repeatUserIds.Contains(x.UserId)).First().MyCol = "somevalue";

    MyEntities.SaveChanges(false);
    scope.Complete();
    MyEntities.AcceptAllChanges();
```

I also have a `List<string>` object called `repeatUserIds` that contains a list of static UserId's, maybe 5 or so.  I want to be able to make my `SomeCollection.Where(x => repeatUserIds.Contains(x.UserId))` statement return the item that has the userid that is OLDEST in the `repeatUserIds` IF there is a match, if no match on `repeatUserIds` (if repeatUserIds.Contains retunrs false), then just return the first item in SomeCollection.

Comment: Use an `OrderBy` first. Just like in plain SQL, result sets *must* be ordered to guarantee ordering.

Comment: What do you mean by 'OLDEST in the repeatUserIds' - the first entry in this list that matches?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote out the wrong code which may have confused many of you, could you please give it another swing? :)

Comment: OK - another swing. What do you mean by 'OLDEST in the repeatUserIds' ? Is `repeatUserIds[0]` "older" than `repeatUserIds[1]` ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov correct, but if `repeatUserIds[0]` is not found in the .where statement, then it would just move to `repeatUserIds[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that in a join the sort order of the first collection is preserved. Thus, the "first" item can be found found in two steps:

```
var dbList = SomeCollection.Where(x => repeatUserIds.Contains(x.UserId))
             .ToList();

repeatUserIds.Join(dbList, s => s, x => x.UserId, (s,x) => x)
             .First().MyCol = "somevalue";
```

Note however that, theoretically, the order of elements in a `List` object is not guaranteed. You may want to use a [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) for the `repeatUserIds`.